# multiple laptops to monitor

Tags: laptop, external-display

I have a monitor which i have connected to a laptop. The laptop and monitor are connected using some kind of USB wire. This allows me to connect my keyboard and mouse to the monitor. I am using VGA for display.

I want to connect another laptop to this monitor and switch between laptops. I do have another DVI port which i can use but i am not sure about how i should make the keyboard and mouse work correctly. There seems to be only one of those outgoing ports (from the monitor) that connect the monitor and laptop.

I am thinking maybe some kind of USB splitter might work which will allow me to plug into two laptops from one outgoing port from the monitor. Again, this will cause keystrokes and mouse movements to be sent to both the laptops but i might be able to live with that. Is this possible? If they exist what are those devices called?

Are there standard/easier ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your after is a KVM. (Keyboard, Video, Monitor)

Its basically a splitter used to connect multiple systems to a single display/Mouse/Keyboard.